# how can I change color of an svg img in base64 format?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an Svg img with in a `base64` format and trying to change the color of it. Does anyone have any pointers of how to do this? I found something about the `<path>` element, but do to the fact that the `svg` img is in a `base64` string I'm not sure of how to use it. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

Comment: It would make more sense to use an inline SVG than putting it in an image tag.  And if you 100% have to use an image tag with a datauri then you don't need to base64 encode it because svgs are human readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*As you do not clarified if can't modify the original file or if must do it on client-side, I propose a*

### Programmatically approach:

1. Lookup the `<img>`
2. From `img.src` strip `"data:image..."`, to extract Base64 encoded SVG.
3. Decode it using [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.atob)
4. Create an element, just for find the `<path>`
5. Set fill on path.
6. Append the new Image or Replace current one.

### Example:

```js
// Lookup the <img> by Id
var img = document.getElementById("target");

// Strip "data:image/svg+xml;base64," to get encoded SVG
var encoded = img.src.substring(26);

// Decode base64
var decoded = atob(encoded);

// Create an HTML element from decoded SVG
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = decoded;
var newSvg = wrapper.firstChild;

// Lookup the <path> and get a ref
var innerPath = newSvg.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];

// Set up new color
innerPath.setAttribute("fill", "#FF0000");

// Show modified image
document.body.appendChild(newSvg);
```

```html
<img id="target" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

### Note:

There are some restrictions on IE < 10

[Can I use atob?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=atob-btoa)

### EDIT: Muplipath Approach

```
var paths = newSvg.getElementsByTagName('path');
[].forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
    path.setAttribute("fill", "#FF0000");
});
```

Comment: how can I do this if i have multiple paths? And select all of them?

Answer (score 4):

For a simple unicolor base64 encoded SVG, you can tweak the color via [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

The filters you need to apply vary. As your base64 encoded SVG is in black unicolor you first `invert` it to white. Then apply `sepia` and `saturate` it properly. Lastly, you tweak the yellow tone you now have via `hue-rotate` to your desired color.

```
img {
  filter: invert(1) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with the help of https://base64.guru:

1. Use https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/svg to convert the base64 code to an SVG, download that SVG, edit it as necessary
2. Use https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/svg to convert your edited SVG back to base64 and copy the resulting code

Fantastic free site, saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Start by decoding the image which is base64-encoded using either a custom [function](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html) or an external [library](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js). You can then write a suitable [string replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to apply to the decoded svg file.

But one question remains: what have you tried?

Comment: i don't really know how to start,

Answer (score 0):

A trick to do convert a `data-uri` into an SVG file using Google Chrome is to:

1. Right click on the `<img>` tag in the DevTools
2. Open the `data:image...` in a new tab using "Open Link in New Tab"
3. Right click on the image in the new tab and "View Page Source"

Now you have the source code of the SVG you can easily change it, for example by modifying the `fill="#f99"` attribute on the `path` to make it appear pink.

I've put the original `<img>` and converted `<svg>` below.

```html
<h2>&lt;img&gt; tag<h2> 
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">

<h2>&lt;svg&gt; tag<h2> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="5.0 -10.0 100.0 135.0" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" height="100px" width="100px">
<path id="path1983_3_" fill="#f99" d="M50.1,4.9v7.4c0,0,0,0-0.2,0c-0.1,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,5.1,0,5.3c0,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4  c0,0.2,0,4.6,0,4.8s-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4c0,0.2,0,1.7,0,1.7l-1.3,3.6c0,0-0.5,0-0.7,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,0.9,0,0.9  s-0.4,0-0.5,0s-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,5.1,0,5.1s-0.4,0-0.5,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,6,0,6.2c0,0.3-0.6,0.4-0.6,0.6  c0,0.2,0,30,0,30s-0.7,0-0.9,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,6.6,0,6.6s-1.8,0-2,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,9.9,0,9.9  s-2.6,0-2.8,0s-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4c0,0.2,0,4.5,0,4.5h25.9c0,0,0-4.3,0-4.5c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-2.8,0-2.8,0s0-9.7,0-9.9  c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-2,0-2,0s0-6.4,0-6.6c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-0.9,0-0.9,0s0-29.8,0-30c0-0.2-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6  c0-0.3,0-6.1,0-6.2c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.5,0s0-5,0-5.1c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-0.6,0-0.6,0s0-0.7,0-0.9  c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4c-0.2,0-0.7,0-0.7,0l-1.3-3.6c0,0,0-1.5,0-1.7c0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.4s0-4.6,0-4.8c0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.4  c0-0.2,0-5.1,0-5.3c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.4s-0.2,0-0.2,0V4.9h-0.4h-0.1H50.1z"/>
<text x="0.0" y="117.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">Created by Lazar Nikolic</text><text x="0.0" y="122.5" font-size="5.0" font-weight="bold" font-family="Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial-Unicode, Arial, Sans-serif" fill="#000000">from the Noun Project</text></svg>
```

Comment: `by adding a stroke="#f99"`. actually you add `fill`.